# How to go about text mining for suggestions/Tips in reviews for restaurants?

Tags: text-mining, nltk

For example for restaurants reviews usually have suggestions like "Go in the evenings", "order the so and so sauce with this dish"  or even "TIP: ask for the blah blah blah"

How can I detect such sentences? How do people usually tackle similar challenges?

Do they create classification rules like `<modal_verb><preference_verb><optional_window_size_of_3><positive_sentiment_words>`
Some examples of these rules are “would be great” and “could be really good”  --
 found this from [here](https://www.experfy.com/blog/suggestion-and-opinion-mining-from-qualitative-surveys).

I guess I would have to use a tagger to categorize words?

Any blog that has attempted something similar step by step?

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I thought about it is - abstractly you are attempting to identify which sentences are, Imperative Mood (IMP) and which are not. One option is to put together a training set/validation set, where each row is a phrase's pos tags (can use some encoder to convert to integers) with a target value of 'isImperative' (binary) then train a model and restructure each review so that they resemble the training set format and have your model assign the values. Seems the easiest and most sustainable method from where I am sitting. Sorry but I don't know any easily accessible phrase data sets but I bet there is one out there somewhere. Hope this helps.